# How to convert a string python single quotes double quotes

Tags: python

New to python. I used a package named pdfminer, in the package, there is a command `pdf2txt.py` used in the following code. I have a problem in single quotes and double quotes. I want to use `os.system()` like this in Windows:

```
os.system('pdf2txt.py -o "E:\PDF\output.txt" "E:\PDF\A Functional Genetic Approach Identifies the PI3K Pathway as a Major Determinant of Trastuzumab Resistance in Breast Cancer.pdf"')
```

In Windows, `"E:\PDF\A Functional Genetic Approach Identifies the PI3K Pathway as a Major Determinant of Trastuzumab Resistance in Breast Cancer.pdf"` must use double quotes.

Now, I use `strSource = "E:\PDF\A Functional Genetic Approach Identifies the PI3K Pathway as a Major Determinant of Trastuzumab Resistance in Breast Cancer.pdf"`, but I use `StrSource` in `os.system()`,it can't get `output.txt`. I think `strSource` may be equal to `'E:\PDF\A Functional Genetic Approach Identifies the PI3K Pathway as a Major Determinant of Trastuzumab Resistance in Breast Cancer.pdf'`. How can I convert the `'` to `"`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to add a fuller section of your code. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is as you say, then you can simply use the `str` `replace` method:

```
strSource = strSource.replace("'", '"')
```

For example,

```
In [1]: strSource = "'E:\PDF\A Functional Genetic Approach ... Cancer.pdf'"

In [2]: print(strSource)
'E:\PDF\A Functional Genetic Approach ... Cancer.pdf'

In [3]: strSource = strSource.replace("'",'"')

In [4]: print(strSource)
"E:\PDF\A Functional Genetic Approach ... Cancer.pdf"
```

Comment: os.system('pdf2txt.py -o "E:\PDF\output.txt" strSource') the output.txt is empty but the pdf is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
strTarget = "E:\PDF\output.txt"
strSource = 'E:\PDF\Vascular_smooth_muscle_contraction.pdf'
os.system('pdf2txt.py -o %s %s' % (self.strTarget,self.strSource))
```

It works!